# How to display/render a 2D image with ARCore (Native Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I need to display a 2D image using ARCore in Android Studio.

Kotlin/Java any language is fine.

I can achieve this using ViewRenderable from SceneForm.
As SceneForm is Archived, I can no longer use it.

You can check out the below video as a reference for what I am trying to achieve.

https://youtu.be/f5IkbuUQwAA

The above video is related to IOS Development -> built with ARKit.

I am trying to achieve same kind of result using ARCore in Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is so sad that sceneform was archived by Google.In the official version **1.17** there are some issues regarding **mavenCentral()**.

However you can use Sceneform 1.15 and that will support `sfb,sfa` and `glTF/glTB` formats.

Meanwhile use this sdk until get any updates from **Google**
https://thomasgorisse.github.io/sceneform-android-sdk/